# Tomcat started in Eclipse but unable to connect to http://localhost:8080

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

Can't see tomcat admin page while starting from eclipse inside.Using OS as Windows 7.

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by

1. switching location under server properties windows.
2. Edit the server 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE3me.png)

Comment: It was because of tomecat modules were not deployed while starting from eclipse. Eclipse default settings use the wtpwebapps location instead of tomcat webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see tomcat home page, you can use following configuration change. 
1. Double click the Tomcat server in the servers tab:
[image: servers tab of the eclipse]

2. Change the Server Locations to Use Tomcat Installation:
   [image: Servers Locations]
3. Save & Restart the server. Now you should see Tomcat Homepage for locathost:8080/:
   [image: Tomcat Homepage]

In the other hand if you fail to start Tomcat server for your application. You need to check web deployment assembly are configured correctly if you use maven. A deployment descriptor folder should be selected correctly.
[image: Configurations for web deployment assembly]

Hope this may help.